# `public void onButton1Clicked(View v)` always make an error

Tags: java, android

I'm just following elementary book of android studio.
So the code is exactly same with the book yet it always show red line under the `(View v)`

In xml,it only has button and edittext.`(no --view)``
But it seems writer of the book doesn't have any problem with that..I have

```
public void onButton1Clicked(View v){

        if(filename.length()>0){
            openPDF(filename.trim());}
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"write pdf-filename", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

It shows red line under `(View v)`, always.
Is it matter of version differences? 
I really don't know why.
Thanks

Comment: What error does the IDE show you? Please post the error message or take a look at the message. It helps you a lot.

Comment: did you try to import the View? (Alt + Enter) in that part.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to import the View Class using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: when I cick alt+Enter, it shows list: create local variable v, create field view v, Rename reference. which should I choose?                   Also the error says: cannot resolve symbol v, ')'expected, ';'expected

Answer (score 0):

> ..yet it always show red line under the (View v)...

This means that your class does not understand what you mean by `View`. The simple way to fix this is to import the View class. To do this, add this line to your list of import statements (right before your class declaration):

```
import android.view.View;
```

**Alternative approach:** It is usually very stressful to memorize package names. Fortunately, android studio has a shortcut for importing missing classes. Simply click on the affected code snippet (the portion of the code that is underlined). After clicking on it, press **ALT** + **ENTER** on your keyboard. With this approach, android studio would automatically import the missing class for you.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can choose this answer as the right answer then.